# Link sendo substituido de forma errada ao usar preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Possuo uma array com expressões regulares que utilizo para substituir url's/hashtags em links usando o `preg_replace`:

```
$regs = array('!(\s|^)((https?://|www\.)+[a-z0-9_./?=;&#-]+)!i', '/#(\w+)/');
$subs = array(' <a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>', '<a href="/hashtag/$1" title="#$1">#$1</a>');

$saida = preg_replace($regs, $subs, $conteudo);
```

Se, o `$conteudo` possuir um link, por exemplo: *https://www.google.com.br/*, ele substitui corretamente; se possuir uma hastag seguida de texto, por exemplo *#boatarde* substitui também, porém, se possuir um link que possua uma hashtag, por exemplo: *https://www.google.com.br/#topo* a substituição fica da seguinte maneira:

> **#topo**" target="_blank">https://www.google.com.br/**#topo**

sendo que, somente as partes em negrito viram links.

Como arrumar?

Comment: o `regex`pra url não seria `^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?`

Comment: Eu estou usando essa que consegui em outra pergunta aqui no StackOverflow, @MaiconCarraro. Sou iniciante em `regex`, porém, a que estou utilizando funciona corretamente, tirando o problema em questão...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma [*lookbehind assertion*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.assertions.php) para verificar se a *hashtag* tem um espaço antes:

```
/(?<=\s)#(\w+)/
```

A substituição não muda pois os grupos começados com `(?` não são capturados